# Sql Query On Joining 3 tables

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I created 3 table as follows

Table Student1:

```
id  status  amount    Name            date
1     0      4500     ram           04/02/2012
2     0      2000    shyam          05/09/2013
4     0      1500    ghanshyam      08/11/2014
```

Table Student2:

```
id   status   amount    Name          date
3      0      4500     gopal       04/02/2012
2      0      8000   radheshyam    15/11/2013
4      1      1500    ghanshyam    18/10/2015
```

Table Student3:

```
id   status   amount    Name          date
1      1      4500     ram         04/02/2012
2      0      6500     radhe       11/11/2014
3      1      4500     gopal       04/02/2012
```

Excepted Result Condition:

1)Select Records with unique "id" from combining 3 tables.

2)Update Field "date" of corresponding record if status=1 of same record with same name,amount in any of the 3 Tables.

3)If 2 or more than 2 record after combining 3 tables with same "id" but other fields different(i.e. Same id but different name,amount,date) then add all them to final result but my appending 1,11,111 to them.

Final Result To be Expected:

```
id  status  amount    Name            date
1     1      4500     ram           04/02/2012
2     0      2000    shyam          05/09/2013
21    0      8000   radheshyam      15/11/2013
211   0      6500     radhe         11/11/2014
3     1      4500     gopal         04/02/2012
4     1      1500    ghanshyam      18/10/2015
```

Sql Fiddle

```
CREATE TABLE Student1
    (`id` int,`status` int,`amount` int , `Name` varchar(10), `date` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO Student1
    (`id`,`status`,`amount`, `Name`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1,0,4500, 'ram', '04/02/2012'),
    (2,0,2000, 'shyam', '05/09/2013'),
    (4,0,1500, 'ghanshyam', '08/11/2014')
;

CREATE TABLE Student2
    (`id` int,`status` int,`amount` int , `Name` varchar(10), `date` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO Student2
    (`id`,`status`,`amount`, `Name`, `date`)
VALUES

    (3,0,4500, 'gopal', '04/02/2012'),
    (2,0,8000, 'radheshyam', '15/11/2013'),
    (4,1,1500, 'ghanshyam', '18/10/2015')
;

CREATE TABLE Student3
    (`id` int,`status` int,`amount` int , `Name` varchar(10), `date` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO Student3
    (`id`,`status`,`amount`, `Name`, `date`)
VALUES

    (1,1,4500, 'ram', '04/02/2012'),
    (2,0,6500, 'radhe', '11/11/2014'),
    (3,1,4500, 'ghanshyam', '04/02/2012')
;
```

Query:

```
 SELECT * FROM Student1
FULL OUTER JOIN Student2
ON Student1.Name = Student2.Name
```

Error:

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN Student2 ON Student1.Name = Student2.Name' at line 2
```

Comment: Why do you have three tables with the same columns?  You seem to have a problem with your data design.

Comment: Really. A **UNION** would be enough, in this case. Actually, **2** UNIONs.

Comment: All the three table are from different sources.So combining all 3 to get final table which will be transferred to all the sources as updated table

Comment: Simply `UNION` the 3 tables.

Comment: But I have to check for all 3 conditions

Comment: UNION skips the duplicate records, if any. You could store the result of the union in a new (temporary) table and perform your aggregations on the required fields. Or you could store the UNION as a View (SQL View, not Android View) and use that View for your calculations. If you need to include the duplicate rows, too, then use UNION ALL.

Comment: I need query as I am new to Sql not having the deep knowledge of query generation

Comment: Maybe you have some time to spend on Google

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82968/discussion-between-lalit-jadiya-and-der-gol-lum).

Answer (score 2):

This would just be a union among those three tables.